# How to create 480 * 800 and layouts for android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-screen-support

I am new to android developer. 480 * 800 not render the proper layout in corresponding resolution mobile

Comment: `480*800` (a.k.a. WVGA) is the typical resolution for **hdpi** (240 dpi) phones. Along with its "cousin" resolution `480*854` (also a.k.a. WVGA)

Answer (score 0):

Please Take a look at this to know the exact resolution for android [Device Metrics](https://design.google.com/devices/) . Anyway, i think you need to create dimension render only for 240dpi layout.